# I have an exterior water tap for a garden hose that needs new caulking

Tags: plumbing

I noticed that the caulking around my outside water tap was beginning to deteriorate and crack. I removed the old caulking to find that the builder had filled the gap where the pipe goes into the brick with bits of wood. I'm guessing this was to help stabilize the pipe, but the wood is beginning to deteriorate as well. Is this common practice for builders and should I remove the wood pieces before proceeding or should I leave them?

Answer (score 2):

The best I can suggest is remove that old wood,it may attract insects as well,I used closed cell spray foam to seal my numerous entry holes,and the closed cell should help stabilize the pipe.If you have acess you could stabilize it with a bracket or hanger if its in the crawl space or basement.Good luck

Comment: +1 Or you could chock it with something inert, like scraps of plastic molding, or other rigid plastics.